# Terminal - How to run the HTTP request 'PUT'

Tags: linux, bash, http, terminal, put

So, what I am trying to do is run from Terminal in Linux an HTTP request, 'PUT'. Not POST, not GET, 'PUT'.

I know in terminal you can just type 'GET http://example.com/', but when I did 'PUT http://example.com' (And a bunch of other variables after that...), Terminal said that PUT is not a command.

Here's what I tried:

```
:~$ PUT http://example.com
PUT: command not found
```

Well, is there a substitute for the command 'PUT', or some way of sending that HTTP request from terminal?

**I don't want to use any external programs.... I don't want to download or install anything. Any other ways?**

Comment: `I know in terminal you can just type 'GET http://example.com/'`. Then you know something I haven't encountered in my 6 years using Linux intensively. It is unusual to have uppercase commands. (And guess where they come from: `libwww-perl`)

Comment: I don't want to have to use any external programs.... I don't want to download anything. Any other ways? (Sorry, I should have specified that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting

```
Terminal said that PUT is not a command.
```

because the information is not being redirected via a network connection (to something that understands HTTP).  bash has *limited* support by itself for communicating over a network, as discussed in

- [Tech Tip: TCP/IP Access Using bash](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-tcpip-access-using-bash)
- [More on Using Bash's Built-in /dev/tcp File (TCP/IP)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Example 29-1. Using /dev/tcp for troubleshooting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html)

Besides that, the [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) says of **`PUT`**:

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.

Clarifying, if you are PUTing to an existing URI, you *may* be able to do this, and the command implictly needs some *data* to reflect a modification.

The example in [HTTP - Methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) (TutorialsPoint) shows a PUT command used to store an HTML body on a URI.  Your script has to redirect the *data* (as well as the initial request) onto the network connection.

You could do all of that using a here-document, or redirecting a file, e.g., (using that example to show how it might be adapted):

```
cat >/dev/tcp/example.com/80 <<EOF
PUT /hello.htm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 182
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

But your script should also provide for reading the server's response.

Answer (score 5):

I would use curl to achieve this: `curl -X PUT http://example.com`

Comment: Well I don't want to have to use any external programs.... I don't want to download anything. Any other ways? (Sorry, I should have specified that!)

Answer (score 2):

`curl -X PUT -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 http://sssss.zzzz`

will work or use postman for HTTP requests www.getpostman.com if terminal is not your main concern, else, CURL is always there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-X` flag with whatever HTTP verb you want:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 localhost:8080
```

This example also uses the -d flag to provide arguments with your PUT request.